# Django: generate div class tag value with max value

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to dynamically create div class tag value for my blocks in Django. I have comments tree and decided to create limit on max value for comment block (only in template not in db). So I created next template. It works fine, but has too big line and I can't insert any spaces and new line symbol, because they break template or keep in page html-source. This is line right after comment.

```
{% extends 'myblog/base.html' %}
{% load bleach_tags %}
{% block title %}{{ article.name|bleach }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'myblog:article_detail' article.id %}"><h2>{{ article.name|bleach }}</h2></a>
    <div class = "post_body_detail">
        {{ article.text|bleach }}
    </div>
    <div class = "comments">
    {% for comment in comment_list %}
        <li>
            {# (next line is too big) div class comment level can not be bigger max value for marking purposes #}
            <div class = "comment{% if comment.level <= comment.MAX_COMMENT_DIV_BLOCK_DEEP %}{{comment.level}}{% else %}comment.MAX_COMMENT_DIV_BLOCK_DEEP{% endif %}">
            {{ comment.text|bleach}}
            </div>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No comments yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

How I can split this line for easier reading (format it)?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How I can split this line for easier reading (format it)?
Spaces and new line symbols break template or adding to page source.

Comment: did my answer respond your question?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{% with max_deep=comment.MAX_COMMENT_DIV_BLOCK_DEEP %} 
    <div
         {% if comment.level <= max_deep %} 
               class="comment{{ comment.level }}"
         {% else %} 
               class="comment{{ max_deep }}"
         {% endif %} 
     >
         {{ comment.text|bleach}}
     </div>
{% endwith %}
```